# How conductive is aluminized mylar?

Tags: microphone, condenser-microphone

So, for my own eccentric reasons, I want to build an honest-to-gosh condenser microphone like they did back in the 1930's (only not as good, I'm sure).

My basic thinking is to use a sheet of aluminum foil or aluminized mylar suspended about 1mm* away from a big pad on a PCB.

Aluminum foil is good because I know it's conductive, but I can just imagine the problems I'm going to have because of its fragility trying to stretch it over a frame.

Aluminized mylar is good because of its mechanical properties, but I'm not sure if typical aluminized mylar from a space blanket or a balloon is going to have a continuous sheet of aluminum on it, or just enough aluminum to make it shiny.

So:

- Does anyone know if "typical" (in the sense that if it's mirror-bright on one side) aluminized mylar is conductive?
- If such "typical" stuff can't be counted on to be conductive, does anyone know the right key words to search for to get stuff that is?  A brief Google search didn't help me out, but I'm quite capable of having awesomely bad Google Fu.

* Or less, limited by my machining abilities.

Comment: MUCH less than 1mm. And aluminised mylar (extracted from high value film caps!) is much much lighter than any Al foil I could lay hands on. Even so, mine were about 15dB less sensitive than ones I could buy... Those had a spacing more like 1 thou (25 microns)

Comment: How big were you making the diaphragm?  I could maybe manage 1 thou if I changed my thinking, and really concentrated on my machining.

Comment: I'm sure the aluminum coating on an MLI blanket is continuous, but I do not know how thick it is.  Did you consider aluminum (used to seal HVAC duct work) or copper tape?  These might have more mass than you're looking for.

Comment: It was actually the project that convinced me I needed a lathe! (of course I never got back to microphones once I got one). My capsules were about 17-20mm diameter. Separation was several thou ... controlled by paper ... and you really need the thinnest lightest film you can get. Not blanket. You might try sourcing gold leaf : in those pre-Internet days I didn't have a clue where. But some real mics use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cut a 2 cm square out of a mylar ['space blanket'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_blanket), and placed my digital multimeter probes flat on either side to measure resistance from one side to the other. The reading (on the 200 Ω scale) was 1.8 Ω.

The sheet thickness was ~0.01 mm (ten layers measured 0.11 mm on my digital calipers). It is only metallized on one side.